# Using Regex to split numbers and expressions

Tags: java, regex, split

I a working on a project where I can accept a string from the user, the user can input negative positive values all in one line.

I then use a regex to split it up on a space. I now need to be able to "fix" the array to have numbers and operators.

```
  "(?<=[\\(\\)\\+\\-*\\/\\^A-Za-z])|(?=[\\(\\)\\+\\-*\\/\\^A-Za-z])"
```

For example a user could input 
-1 /2 - 1/2

I now need elements to be like 
arr[1] = -1
arr[2] = 2 (or / would also be fine)

Currently it does:

-

1

/

2

-

1

/

2

I started writing cases to be like if arr[i].equals("-") then grab the next number also. Well that wont work since they can have a - in the middle.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe, some expression similar to

```
-?\s*[0-9.]+|([+÷*-])
```

might be OK to start with, if validation would be done afterwards.

There might be some design issues in what you might be trying to accomplish here though.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgZFTM/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "-?\\s*[0-9.]+|([+÷*-])";
        final String string = "-1 /2 - 1/2.4\n"
             + "-1 /25 -- 1/23.2\n"
             + "-1 / 29 - 1/212.42\n"
             + "-1 / 2 - -1/2\n"
             + "-1 / 2 * -1/2\n"
             + "-1 / 2 + -1/2\n"
             + "-1 / 2 ÷ -1/2";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Full match: - 1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2.4
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 25
Group 1: null
Full match: -
Group 1: -
Full match: - 1
Group 1: null
Full match: 23.2
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match:  29
Group 1: null
Full match: - 1
Group 1: null
Full match: 212.42
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match:  2
Group 1: null
Full match: -
Group 1: -
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match:  2
Group 1: null
Full match: *
Group 1: *
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match:  2
Group 1: null
Full match: +
Group 1: +
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match:  2
Group 1: null
Full match: ÷
Group 1: ÷
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
```

---

If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
explained on the top right panel of
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RMrzv0/1/). If you'd like, you
can also watch in [this
link](https://regex101.com/r/RMrzv0/1/debugger), how it would match
against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: To further expand my problem, say I want to be able to extract the operator in the middle. (fraction sorta say) -1 / 2 - -1/2 for example should read as (-1/2) - (-1/2)